# Dynamically allocated two dimensional (double) array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to dynamically allocate two dimensional array N+1xN with all elements double. Then I want to put value (1.6) for each element of an array. The last step is to print this array. 
My function

```
void inic(double **t)
{
    for(int y=0;y<N;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<N+1;x++)
        {
            t[x][y]=1.5;
        }
    }
}
```

isn't working as it should and I don't know why.

For example the (for n=3) result is:

```
[0][0][0][0] 
[0][0][0][0] 
[0][0][0][0]
```

And I expected:

```
[1.6][1.6][1.6][1.6] 
[1.6][1.6][1.6][1.6] 
[1.6][1.6][1.6][1.6] 
[1.6][1.6][1.6][1.6]
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int N;

void inic(double **t)
{
    for(int y=0;y<N;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<N+1;x++)
        {

            t[x][y]=1.5;

        }
    }
}

void print(double **t)
{
    for(int y=0;y<N;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<N+1;x++)
        {
            printf("%i ",t[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}




int main()
{
    double **t;
    N=3;
    t=malloc((N+1)*sizeof(double*));
    for(int i=0;i<N+1;i++)
    {
        t[i]=malloc(N*sizeof(double));
    }

    inic(t);
    print(t);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: `double **` is not a 2D array and cannot point to one. You can allocate a 2D array dynamically without problem, why not use it? And "my code is not working" is not a **specific** problem description.

Comment: In the first place, your array has (N+1).N elements, not N+1.

Comment: How do you expect it to have `1.6` if you put everywhere `1.5`???? :)

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/

Comment: 3) Using pointer to a pointer

Comment: I tried to do the same as in the following code. :) however I didn't write (**double) brace in  t=(**double) malloc((N+1)*sizeof(double*));

Comment: You say "double **" is not even an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect conversion specifier. Try the following

```
printf("%lf ",t[x][y]);
```

Also it would be more natural to use another order of the indices that is when 
this statement

```
t=malloc((N)*sizeof(double*));
```

allocates N "rows" and then the N + 1 "columns" are allocated in the loop

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    t[i]=malloc( ( N + 1 )*sizeof(double));
}
```

In this case other functions will look like

```
void inic(double **t)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < N; x++)
    {
        for( int y = 0;  y < N + 1; y++ )
        {

            t[x][y]=1.5;

        }
    }
}

void print(double **t)
{
    for( int x = 0; x < N; x++ )
    {
        for( int y = 0; y < N + 1; y++)
        {
            printf("%lf ",t[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Also you should free all the allocated memory at the end of the program.

Comment: It worked however I had to change: "printf("%lf ",t[x][y]);" for "printf("%f ",t[x][y]);". :D

Answer (score 1):

try to replace `t[x][y]` to `t[y][x]`

Comment: also replace `printf("%i ",t[y][x]);` to `printf("%f ",t[y][x]);`